# Pop OS theme for Ubuntu 18.04 boot problem

Tags: boot, 18.04, themes, secure-boot

I installed Pop OS theme for Ubuntu. As a result the PC doesn't start except with Secure Boot disabled. Why doesn't it start with secure boot Secure Boot enabled?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop   
sudo apt install pop-theme    

Start-Date: 2019-07-21  15:34:02
Commandline: apt install pop-theme
Requested-By: t (1000)
Install: pop-gnome-shell-theme:amd64 (4.0.12~1559836915~18.04~d27d536, automatic), gnome-themes-standard:amd64 (3.28-1ubuntu1, automatic), pop-theme:amd64 (1.0.3~1513028740~18.04~3b8d142), pop-fonts:amd64 (1.0.3~1555617065~18.04~a86eb73, automatic), pop-gtk-theme:amd64 (4.1.4~1560290633~18.04~f75e86a, automatic), pop-icon-theme:amd64 (1.4.0~1561150402~18.04~9f57443, automatic)
End-Date: 2019-07-21  15:34:25

Start-Date: 2019-07-21  15:39:04
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.107'
Install: linux-headers-5.0.0-21:amd64 (5.0.0-21.22+system76, automatic), linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-21.22+system76, automatic), linux-headers-5.0.0-21-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-21.22+system76, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-21-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-21.22+system76, automatic), libsoxr0:amd64 (0.1.2-3, automatic), linux-modules-5.0.0-21-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-21.22+system76, automatic), pigz:amd64 (2.4-1, automatic)
Upgrade: libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1, 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1pop1), libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.1, 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.1pop1), gnome-control-center-data:amd64 (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.5~1558109272~18.04~56507d7), dmsetup:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.1, 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu3.18.04.1pop1), gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.5~1558109272~18.04~56507d7), libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 (3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1, 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1pop1), libgoa-1.0-common:amd64 (3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1, 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1pop1), libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2, 1:12.2-9~bionic1), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2, 1:12.2-9~bionic1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (4.18.0.25.74, 5.0.0.21.78+system76), gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0:amd64 (0.6.45-1ubuntu1, 0.6.45-1ubuntu1pop2), plymouth-label:amd64 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2, 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.pop0), plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2, 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.pop0), gdm3:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.5pop1~1551986836~18.04~d21ecd7), xkb-data:amd64 (2.23.1-1ubuntu1, 2.23.1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1~pop0), initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.130ubuntu3.8, 0.130ubuntu3.8pop1), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.5pop1~1551986836~18.04~d21ecd7), libplymouth4:amd64 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2, 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.pop0), libgdm1:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.5pop1~1551986836~18.04~d21ecd7), libpulse0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2, 1:12.2-9~bionic1), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2, 1:12.2-9~bionic1), linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (4.18.0.25.74, 5.0.0.21.78+system76), linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (4.18.0.25.74, 5.0.0.21.78+system76), gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64 (3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1, 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1pop1), gnome-online-accounts:amd64 (3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1, 3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1pop1), linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (4.18.0.25.74, 5.0.0.21.78+system76), plymouth:amd64 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2, 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.pop0), gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.5~1558109272~18.04~56507d7), pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2, 1:12.2-9~bionic1), accountsservice:amd64 (0.6.45-1ubuntu1, 0.6.45-1ubuntu1pop2), plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:amd64 (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2, 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.pop0), pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2, 1:12.2-9~bionic1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7, 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7pop1), initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.130ubuntu3.8, 0.130ubuntu3.8pop1), initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.130ubuntu3.8, 0.130ubuntu3.8pop1), libaccountsservice0:amd64 (0.6.45-1ubuntu1, 0.6.45-1ubuntu1pop2)
End-Date: 2019-07-21  15:41:47
```

Comment: How did you install "pop os theme"? Did you use a ppa? Which one? And what other packages were installed at the time? There are other questions here dealing with a variety of issues associated with installing https://launchpad.net/~system76/+archive/ubuntu/pop/+packages.

Comment: Was anything else installed by way of dependencies when you ran `sudo apt install pop-theme`? You could look at */var/log/apt/history.log* in case you aren't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the system76/pop theme on Ubuntu. It is designed for the Pop!_OS! Linux distribution, which while based on Ubuntu, isn't Ubuntu. The maintainers of the ppa added the following warning to the PPA home screen.

```
WARNING: This PPA is for Pop!_OS, and it may cause breakage on other Ubuntu-based OS's. Use of this repository on non-Pop_OS installations is at your own risk!
```